# How to tell where the source code of official Python packages is?

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

When a tutorial suggests installing a Python package via `pip` or `easy_install`, how might one determine where the original official code repository is?

For instance, the [Python Yelp API Examples](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/tree/master/v2/python) suggest installing `sudo easy_install oauth2` however I would prefer to download the packages myself from the official repo. I've googled for `python oauth` and found quite a few 'competing' packages. I *think* that [this one](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) is the official package (due to being linked from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oauth2/)) but I would like to know **which chain of examination would lead to the official package source code**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no one way to determine the repo of a package listed on PyPI. It is up to the author to document this for you.

When you use `easy_install oauth2`, you instruct `easy_install` to load the PyPI-registered project `oauth2`, located at `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/<project-name>`, which should be your first port of call if you are looking for repository information.

The [`oauth2` PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oauth2) documents a homepage: https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2

This is the link provided in the [`setup.py` metadata for this project](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/blob/master/setup.py#L33), and that's as far as you get with examining this. If the author put in the wrong link, then there is little you can do to verify this.

To me, there is no doubt that `https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/` is the source code you'd install when you run `easy_install oauth2`.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation Martijn!